# BN curves in Charm crypto library

Tags: implementation

I'm using Charm to implement a scheme and I know it has "SS512", "MNT159" and "prime192v1". I don't know if Charm includes BN curve? If it doesn't, how to implement it with Charm.

Answer (score 0):

According to this file [pairingcurves.py](https://github.com/JHUISI/charm/blob/v0.43/charm/toolbox/pairingcurves.py) in the Charm repo, you should be able to implement BN groups too. I have not implemented it personally but I think this should work:

```py
from charm.toolbox.pairinggroup import PairingGroup,ZR,G1,G2,GT,pair
group = PairingGroup('BN158')
```

You can further refer to the Charm-crypto [docs](https://jhuisi.github.io/charm/cryptographers.html) here.

I know this answer is a bit late, but hope it helps :-)

Answer (score 0):

There are included BN curves in Charm but they are only 'BN158', 'BN254', and 'BN256'. If you require a different curve, you can use the `genfparams`
executable program included in PBC library. Charm is a wrapper of PBC so you have `genfparams` (or `genfparams.c` if it is not already compiled) inside your Charm directory or in the include directory.

The `genfparams` program generates the needed parameters for a BN curve with a target order of the underlying groups. If you know the order of the groups used for the curve you need, then you can use `genfparams` to produce the rest of the parameters. When you get the parameters, copy and paste the results in the `pairingcurves.py` file following the format indicated in that file. You will understand this when you see it.